# Error: 'Attempted to perform another operation with a fetch already in progress', Only in iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios6, xcode5

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempted to perform another operation with a fetch already in progress'**

First time my application working fine..but then after every time my app is crashed due to the above error and its only happened in **iOS6** version devices. but my app is working fine in **iOS7** or upper version devices.

The below is stack trace:

```
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x32e5b2bb <redacted> + 186
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3aadb97f objc_exception_throw + 30
2   CoreData                            0x32bf5207 <redacted> + 94
3   CoreData                            0x32bf591d <redacted> + 92
4   CoreData                            0x32c06387 <redacted> + 58
5   CoreData                            0x32c04d19 <redacted> + 624
6   CoreData                            0x32bfe089 <redacted> + 312
7   CoreData                            0x32bfd73f <redacted> + 682
8   CoreData                            0x32bfd205 <redacted> + 468
9   CoreData                            0x32bfc61d <redacted> + 1644
10  CoreData                            0x32bfaf17 <redacted> + 646
11  WhatDidIWear                        0x000b1875 -[WDIWDatabase(Years) years] + 848
12  WhatDidIWear                        0x000a9b2d -[WDIWCalendar years] + 56
13  WhatDidIWear                        0x00095c8f -[YearsViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] + 382
14  WhatDidIWear                        0x000945bb -[TemplateViewController initWithDefaultNibName] + 62
15  WhatDidIWear                        0x00093567 -[TabBarController yearsVC] + 134
16  WhatDidIWear                        0x00093713 -[TabBarController homeViewControllers] + 46
17  WhatDidIWear                        0x0008f49b -[TabBarController viewDidLoad] + 510
18  UIKit                               0x34cf82d5 <redacted> + 228
19  WhatDidIWear                        0x0008e927 -[AppDelegate tabBarController] + 134
20  WhatDidIWear                        0x0008de65 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 980
21  UIKit                               0x34cc3ad9 <redacted> + 252
22  UIKit                               0x34cc3663 <redacted> + 1190
23  UIKit                               0x34cbb84b <redacted> + 698
24  UIKit                               0x34c63c39 <redacted> + 1004
25  UIKit                               0x34c636cd <redacted> + 72
26  UIKit                               0x34c6311b <redacted> + 6154
27  GraphicsServices                    0x369555a3 <redacted> + 590
28  GraphicsServices                    0x369551d3 <redacted> + 34
29  CoreFoundation                      0x32e30173 <redacted> + 34
30  CoreFoundation                      0x32e30117 <redacted> + 138
31  CoreFoundation                      0x32e2ef99 <redacted> + 1384
32  CoreFoundation                      0x32da1ebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
33  CoreFoundation                      0x32da1d49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
34  UIKit                               0x34cba485 <redacted> + 668
35  UIKit                               0x34cb7301 UIApplicationMain + 1120
36  WhatDidIWear                        0x0008d97f main + 230
37  libdyld.dylib                       0x3af12b20 <redacted> + 0
```

)

I am frustrated now for not solving the above error.

Please give me an idea to solve the above stuff.

Comment: Post the stacktrace.  Without it you'll never find out where the problem is (well you might, but it'll take ages).

Comment: @trojanfoe - Please refer the above stacktrace.

Comment: Well the exception is generated by CoreData, but as I don't use CoreData I have no real experience with the absolute cause.  My hunch is that you've failed to close a statement, or whatever the equivalent is, before starting another transaction.

Comment: Same here this app is already built by others and i have to update some features in it. and i haven't any experience with CoreData.

Comment: Oh well, you're about to get some.